# Why is PyTorch inference faster when preloading all mini-batches to list?

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, multiprocessing, profiling, dataloader

While benchmarking different dataloaders I noticed some peculiar behavior with the PyTorch built-in dataloader. I am running the below code on a cpu-only machine with the MNIST dataset.

It seems that a simple forward pass in my model is much faster when mini-batches are preloaded to a list rather than fetched during iteration:

```
import torch, torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as T
from torch.profiler import profile, record_function, ProfilerActivity

 

mnist_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=".", train=True, transform=T.ToTensor(), download=True)
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=mnist_dataset, batch_size=128,shuffle=False, pin_memory=False, num_workers=4)
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(28*28, 256), nn.BatchNorm1d(256), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(256, 10))
model.train()

 

with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
        for (images_iter, labels_iter) in loader:
            outputs_iter = model(images_iter)
print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=10))

 

with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
        train_list = [sample for sample in loader]
        for (images_iter, labels_iter) in train_list:
            outputs_iter = model(images_iter)
print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=10))
```

The subset of most interesting output from the Torch profiler is:

```
Name                Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls
aten::batch_norm         0.02%     644.000us         4.57%     134.217ms     286.177us           469
Self CPU time total: 2.937s
```

```
Name                 Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls
aten::batch_norm        70.48%        6.888s        70.62%        6.902s      14.717ms    469
Self CPU time total: 9.773s
```

Seems like aten::batch_norm (batch normalization) is taking significantly more time in the case where samples are not preloaded to a list, but I can't figure out why since it should be the same operation?

The above was tested on a 4-core cpu with python 3.8

If anything the version of pre-loading to a list should be slight slower overall due to the overhead of creating the list

Answer (score 0):

with

```
torch=1.10.2+cu102
torchvision=0.11.3+cu102
```

had following results

```
Self CPU time total: 2.475s
Self CPU time total: 2.800s
```

Try to reproduce this code again using different lib versions